# How to edit src of <figure> dynamically in js

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to edit the src attribute of img inside `<figure>` HTML tag but am surprised to know that src is not an attribute on the figure (might be wrong).

```
<figure data-asset-id="dfdsf"><img src="https:/assets/conference-gffe9859b2_640.jpg" data-asset-id="dfdsf" data-image-id="dfdsf" alt="conference pic"></figure>
```

with  `document.getAttribute` on figure it returned

```
<img src="https://assets/conference-gffe9859b2_640.jpg" data-asset-id="dfdsf" data-image-id="dfdsf" alt="conference pic">
```

as a **string** so thought of converting it into HTML using DOM Parser but didn't work out for me.

any clue what I might be missing?

For those who aren't aware of the HTML `<figure>` element. A standard `<figure>` element looks like below

```
<figure>
  <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Trulli" style="width:100%">
  <figcaption>Fig.1 - Trulli, Puglia, Italy.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

---

If someone is looking for the answer

```
const figureEle = document.querySelector("[data-asset-id='dfdsf']")
const ChildImg = figureEle.childNodes[0]
ChildImg.setAttribute('src',newURL)
```

Not sure if it's the best BUT it does the job.

Comment: A `figure` element acts as a parent of an `img` element (also parent of `figcaption` element). So it would be expected it doesn't have a src attribute. You can however set your image as `background-image` of either its `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements though and change it that way. Or are you just wanting to change the src of the `IMG` element INSIDE that `figure` element?

Comment: unclear what you actually tried. Figure is an element and does not have a src. The image element inside has a src attribute. Not sure what you are doing with saying you need to convert it.

Comment: @ChrisW. I want to change the src of IMG element inside that figure element

Comment: @epascarello . I'm not sure what you mean when you say -"Figure is an element and does not have a src" . This link might help https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figure.asp

Comment: @user269867 the image tag inside has a src, not the figure tag.

Comment: Please don't edit questions to include the answer. Instead post the answer as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img id="uniqueId" src="https:/assets/conference-gffe9859b2_640.jpg" data-asset-id="dfdsf" data-image-id="dfdsf" alt="conference pic">
```

In JS, after loading or on any event/function

```
getElementById('uniqueId').src = 'newURL'
```

or by button

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('uniqueId').src='newURL'">Turn off the light</button>
```

Comment: You should never use the HTML event handler attributes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these

Answer (score -1):

Your `<figure>` element does not appear to have a src attribute but the `<img>` element does. In either case, first select the element, then get/set the attribute. There is a shortcut for `.src`.

```
document.querySelector("img").src;

document.querySelector("figure").setAttribute("name", "helloButton");
```

Comment: If you noticed the img is inside <figure> .A standard <figure> element looks like <figure>
  <img src="pic_trulli.jpg" alt="Trulli" style="width:100%">
  <figcaption>Fig.1 - Trulli, Puglia, Italy.</figcaption>
</figure>. Now tell me how would you dynamically change the image inside <figure>

Comment: You change it just like any other HTML element. First, select it, then modify it as you want. In case of an `<img>`, `document.querySelector("img")` works.